# List of UITableView Rows That Are NOT Selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios6, nsmutablearray

I have the following code.

```
NSMutableArray *aList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in tableview1.indexPathsForSelectedRows) {
    NSString *r = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];
    [aList addObject:r];
}
```

So what I get is a list of UITableView rows that are selected.  Is there a simple way of getting a **list** of rows that are **NOT** selected?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There may be elegant solutions but this will work.

```
    NSMutableArray *allIndexPaths = [@[]mutableCopy];
    NSInteger nSections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
    for (int j=0; j<nSections; j++) {
        NSInteger nRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j];
        for (int i=0; i<nRows; i++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j];
            [allIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        }
    }

    NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows;

    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in selectedIndexPaths) {
        [allIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    }

    NSArray *unselectedIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithArray:allIndexPaths];
```

EDIT : As per [Rikkles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401029/rikkles) suggestion

```
NSMutableArray *unselectedIndexPaths = [@[]mutableCopy];
NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows;
NSInteger nSections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
for (int j=0; j<nSections; j++) {
    NSInteger nRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j];
    for (int i=0; i<nRows; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j];
        if (![selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
            [unselectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  It doesn't appear that your code gives me what I need.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems close to what I need except that what I need is a list of rows not indexPaths, you know?

Comment: @TBlue You can easily filter it again giving the section of indexPath.

Comment: This is inefficient. You're looping too much, and it is useless to waste all the cycles creating and adding to `allIndexPaths`. Loop once, test and discard what you don't need. (see my answer)

Comment: @Rikkles You are correct. Your's is more efficient. I'm editing my code giving you the credit :)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array]; // that's all unselected indexPaths
NSArray *l = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
NSIndexPath *idx;
for (NSUInteger sec=0; sec<[self.tableView numberOfSections]; sec++) {
  for (NSUInteger r=0; r<[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:sec]; r++) {
    idx = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:sec];
    if(![l containsObject:idx]){
      [a addObject:idx];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I cannot get your code to work.  An error occurs at the line where you have [self.tableView indexPathForRow:r inSection:sec] .

Comment: There was a missing ';' on that line. Apologies.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I think it was the second line.

Comment: Yes my mistake, the method is for NSIndexPath. Fixed. Incidentally, this code is faster than the accepted answer. You only loop once through all the rows. The accepted answer loops once through all the rows, and then through the selected rows.

Comment: Okay.  Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the numberOfRows return value minus the total selected rows.

Comment: to get what!? - the number of rows that are not selected?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray * yourNewArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] init];

for(NSUInteger i = 0 ; i < [yourArr count] ; i++){

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]; 

    NSArray *selIndexs = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows;

    if(![selIndexs containsObject:indexPath]){

        [yourNewArr addObject:indexPath];                          
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", yourNewArr); // this will contain unselected index paths.
```

Comment: Thanks.  What is loopPath?

Comment: should it not be if(![selIndexs containsObject:indexPath])?

Comment: You still have a few typos (i.e. yourArr, j).  Even after I correct them, your code will return nothing.

Comment: yourArr is the array that you are using as datasource - i just gave it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I've added several additional lines to Anupdas' code.  He certainly deserves the entire credit.

```
    NSMutableArray *allIndexPaths = [@[]mutableCopy];
    NSInteger nSections = [tableview1 numberOfSections];
    for (int j=0; j < nSections; j++) {
        NSInteger nRows = [tableview1 numberOfRowsInSection:j];
        for (int i=0; i<nRows; i++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j];
            [allIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        }
    }
    NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = tableview1.indexPathsForSelectedRows;
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in selectedIndexPaths) {
        [allIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    }

    NSMutableArray *bList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger k = 0; k < allIndexPaths.count; k++) {
        NSString *r = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[allIndexPaths objectAtIndex:k] row]];
        [bList addObject:r];
    }
```